# Centos 7 rsyslog service issue

Tags: boot, process, rsyslog

I have a problem concerning rsyslog. After system reboot, the service does not start after a few tries. I noticed, that pid file still exists after reboot, and after rm /var/run/syslogd.pid I can normally start the service. How can I fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just have to enable it with `systemctl enable syslog.service`
That should ensure it launches at boot

Can you print the result  of `systemctl status syslog.service` ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your simple idea made my think. Looks like both rsyslog and syslog-ng service were enabled by accident. I just disable one of them and the error disappeared.